# Alcor Multi Flash Reader Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, sd-card

OS: Arch Linux
Hardware: Toshiba S55

lsusb -v

```
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 058f:6366 Alcor Micro Corp. Multi Flash Reader
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.01
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x058f Alcor Micro Corp.
  idProduct          0x6366 Multi Flash Reader
  bcdDevice            1.00
  iManufacturer           1 
  iProduct                2 
  iSerial                 3 
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           32
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0xa0
      (Bus Powered)
      Remote Wakeup
    MaxPower              100mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass         8 Mass Storage
      bInterfaceSubClass      6 SCSI
      bInterfaceProtocol     80 Bulk-Only
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x01  EP 1 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
```

lspci

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 06)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x16 Controller (rev 06)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller (rev 06)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev d4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev d4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev d4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM86 Express LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK208M [GeForce GT 740M] (rev ff)
03:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA8171 Gigabit Ethernet (rev 10)
```

The OS doesn't seem to detect my SDHC card when I insert it. Does Linux support this hardware?

ls /dev/sd*

```
/dev/sda  /dev/sda1  /dev/sda2  /dev/sda3  /dev/sda4  /dev/sda5  /dev/sd
```

Comment: Maybe you need some drivers. My computer (Arch as well) didn't use to detect the touch-pad, I had to install an additional driver.

Comment: @JMCF125 How did you find the appropriate drivers?

Comment: [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Touchpad_Synaptics)! I just googled "touch pad arch linux", and installed `extra/xf86-input-synaptics`. Possibly if you do the same with the card type, and brand if the type isn't enough, it might work.

Comment: It seems we are in trouble. Have you considered this: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1136196 ? Can we verify that at least does read simple small size SD and not SDHC? Perhaps trying it with a much earlier kernel version?

Comment: @user2383408 I don't have any SD cards. Is there a way to test the card reader without SD cards?

Comment: @ArchHaskeller - no, there isn't - or at least not that I discovered, though I guess you could do something weird with it on a serial terminal... I can tell you the very same SD reader worked fine for me in Arch Linux on the laptop in the link, though it's impossible to boot from it. One weird thing about it though was that the webcam and reader were on the same bus so if the webcam was disabled in some way the reader wouldn't operate. http://www.asus.com/Notebooks_Ultrabooks/U56E/

Comment: What is your kernel version? Also, what is the output of `dmesg | tail` after you insert the device?